# Where can I download the Synaptics Touchpad suite?

Tags: touchpad, trackpad

On Synaptics website, they advertise the Synaptics Touchpad suite for Linux, but it is not available for download.  Am I looking in the wrong place?  How do I get a hold of this?

This would solve my clickpad problems that people are currently hacking around...

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer(s) to your question when possible (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean the [Synaptics *Gesture* Suite](http://www.synaptics.com/solutions/technology/touchpad-linux), which provides enhanced multitouch functionality, etc., not basic pointing drivers.

Sorry, even though it's "free", Synaptics has decreed you can only get that from your laptop manufacturer, presumably one who has decided to play very friendly with Linux (and those are few!):

> SGS-L is provided free of charge to Synaptics OEM/ODM partners when ordered with Synaptics TouchPad and ClickPad™ products. To find out more about Synaptics Gesture Suite for Linux, please contact your Synaptics sales representative.

Comment: Synaptics killing the passion...