# Turn on Touchpad Momentum feature in ubuntu

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptics

I am using both Ubuntu 13.04 and windows.

I am used to touchpad momentum feature in windows using my driver software for synaptic touchpad, but I cannot use that feature in Ubuntu as only a few multi touch features can be enabled.

I installed Synaptiks in ubuntu, but it does not provide that momentum feature.

Is there any way to enable touchpad momentum feature in ubuntu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe there is any way to do this at the moment. You would need to get a copy of Synaptic Gesture Pack and from what I have researched that is a tough thing to come by. You can read a older question asked about the Touchpad suite here.
[Where can I download the Synaptics Touchpad suite?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156199/where-can-i-download-the-synaptics-touchpad-suite)

The synaptic website has some info on it here as well [Synaptic Gesture Suite](http://www.synaptics.com/en/gesture-suite-linux.php)